# Searching support ticket software

Tags: gratis, email, project-management, issue-tracker

I'm searching a support ticket software. It should be free, and it would be great if it would had an app. Sounds simple, but I didn't found anything free. Do you know a good support ticket software? It can be hosted or to install on my own server (only PHP or such things, no complete software like Spiceworks).

Comment: Doesn't look like your search has been that extensive :) I've just added two tags to your question. Please start with the questions using those and have answers: [project-management](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=[project-management]+answers%3A1) & [issue-tracker](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=[issue-tracker]+answers%3A1). *Trac* might be a fitting solution (it's among the recommendations).

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to recommend osTicket. It's an open source ticket system and can be run on your own server (just using PHP & MySQL). It's pretty simple but very powerful. It doesn't have its own app but it can be accessed by any device that has a browser. It has quite a few features too including,

- Custom Fields
- Rich Text HTML for Emails
- Ticket Filters
- Assign and Transfer Tickets to other techs
- Auto-Responder Email System
- Online portal for clients
- Dashboard Reports

Also, with the email system, you can link an email account (or depending on the server you can direct all emails to a script within the ticket system) and clients can email back and forth through just their email without having to visit the online portal.

## [osTicket](http://www.osticket.com/) ([open source](https://github.com/osTicket/))

> osTicket is a widely-used open source support ticket system. It
> seamlessly integrates inquiries created via email, phone and web-based
> forms into a simple easy-to-use multi-user web interface. Manage,
> organize and archive all your support requests and responses in one
> place while providing your customers with accountability and
> responsiveness they deserve.
>
> osTicket is an attractive alternative to higher-cost and complex
> customer support systems; simple, lightweight, reliable, open source,
> web-based and easy to setup and use. The best part is, it's completely
> free.
>
> [image: osTicket Dashboard example]

Comment: I have used many support ticket systems, and osTicket is, without a doubt, the best one I have ever used, even including paid commercial products.